# How to leave the R browser() mode in the console window?

Tags: r, debugging

I was trying to use the `browser()` command to debug earlier.

Right now, I kept getting the following in the console input window:

```
Browse[13]>
```

Is it possible to get out of this situation and just get back to  the normal console window?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The help page `?browser` says that typing `c` and hitting enter will get you out of the browser and let the function continue to run or typing `Q` and hitting enter will exit the browser and the function and take you back to the top-level prompt.

Comment: I've wondered this myself but was always to lazy to look.  Q seems to shut the entire browser down and exit the function (return to console).  Particularly nice if you used it inside of an `lapply` as in: `lapply(1:10, function(i){ browser(); mean(rnorm(10))})` +1

Comment: @user2806363, it should be "c" not "C".  How are you calling `browser` and what version of R are you using?  what happens when you type "Q", "c", etc.?  If it truly is not working, and is not the fault of a 3rd party interface, then you should file a bug report.

Comment: @GregSnow I've also had a similar problem, "c" and "f" didn't work, but "Q" did. I'm using R mode in ESS. http://pastebin.com/gyLtVCxb

Comment: @Dmitri, do they work when running R directly (not through ESS)?  If so then this is an ESS problem and should be reported there.

Comment: Note that R is case-sensitive. `q` does not work, but `Q` does.

Comment: none of those are working for me. debugging wasn't '"on"" a specific function - but was on all time while i was writing codes. I can't turn it off

Comment: @Jneven, what interface are you using? (RStudio? ESS? other?) Did you hand insert `browser()`? or use some other debugging tool? in case, which tool?

Comment: This should be more intuitive. I tried `exit()`, `quit()`, `q()`, ctrl + c, ctrl + d, escape, `:`, enter, `browser()`, `n`, and a few others before having to google. Perhaps just the traditional ctrl + c would be ideal.

Answer (score 8):

You will actually need to first enter f press enter and then enter Q. The order is finish and then quit. Otherwise you might not leave the browsing.

Answer (score 6):

Turn off global debugging

```
debuggingState(on=FALSE)
```